# Angular 6, ngc, AOT, Angular Router, router.ngfactory and SystemJS

Tags: angular, systemjs, angular-compiler-cli, angular-compiler

I have a simple angular 6 application I am trying to get compiled with AOT.  ***I am NOT using the Angular CLI***.  I have a custom generator that scaffolds my project start and scaffolds my components, services, etc.

Everything works as expected pre-AOT.  When i run ngc to compile my angular application everything compiles without errors.  However when I check the compiled ngfactory javascript files, I see a reference for @angular/router/router.ngfactory from node_modules directory.  I can't seem to locate this file anywhere.

My configuration is as follows:

- Node v.10.10.0
- Angular v.6.1.2
- Typescript v.3.1.1
- SystemJS v 0.21.4
- Gulp v.3.9.1

I created a sample repo to replicate the issue.

The repo is located at [SlyGenerator.DemoWithAOT](https://github.com/DavisSylvester/SlyGenerator.DemoWithAOT)

To start the application normally with JIT run the following command  "npm run start-dev"

To reproduce the error

- I run "node_modules/.bin/ngc -p ./src/assets/ts/tsconfig.aot.json"  This produces a "dist" folder at the root level with the ngfactory files.
- I then copy content of the dist folder to ./app/assets/js/  (This allows me to test the generated code without bundling or minification.
- Next I modify my system.config.js file to use the Main.aot.js file instead of Main.js file.  System.config.js file is located in .app/assets/config/system.config.js

At this point I get the following error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I can switch the system.config.js file back to the original and everything works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

After troubleshooting for a view days.  I found out the issue was related to a missing library / feature module.

IMO the > error generally has to do with missing files.